# Loop to create histograms to check if data is normalized

Tags: r, function, loops, histogram

I am trying to create a function and then loop over it to save me some (time - perhaps not anymore) but also code making the code more transparent.

The code does not print anything and I fail to see the issue.

This is the code I'm using:

```
# Generate histograms
create_histogram <- function(baseline_data, variable_name, Randomization, bin_width = 6) {
  plot <- ggplot(baseline_data, aes_string(x = variable_name)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width, color = "black", fill = "lightblue") +
    facet_wrap(as.formula(paste0("~ ", Randomization))) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = paste0(variable_name, " Histogram by Group"),
         x = variable_name,
         y = "Frequency")
  return(plot)
}
print(ggplot(baseline_data, aes(x = age)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 6, color = "black", fill = "grey") +
  facet_wrap(~ Randomization) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Age Histogram by Group", x = "Age", y = "Frequency")
)
# List of variables

variables <- c("age", "BMI")
for (variable in variables) {
  plot <- create_histogram(baseline_data, variable, "Randomization")
  print(plot)
}
```

I tried to code above and was hoping to create several histograms within the few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error or at least a solution to the problem.

What I did was:

```
column_names <- colnames(baseline_data)
```

and then insted of using the string names of the the variables I used the integer

```
variables <- column_names[c(127, 128)]
```

This made the code work :)